# Blogger - Set the date of publication of the entry in the future

Tags: php, google-api, blogger, google-api-php-client

I am assuming that I use the following code to add a new post. How to set the date to make public post?

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application\Controller;
set_time_limit (300);

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
    Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest;

use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Http\Cookies;
use Zend\Http\Header;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;
use Zend\Json\Json;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
$client = new \Google_Client();
$redirectUri='http://czystyping.dev/application/index/index';$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
//$scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];///.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('Blogspot');
//$client->setAuthConfigFile('Blogspot-b4ae4.json');
$client->setClientId('st.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('my-secret-string');
$client->setDeveloperKey('INSERT DEV HERE'); // API key
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger");
$service = new \Google_Service_Blogger($client);


if(isset($authUrl)) {
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
   print "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
  }
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    die('Logged out.');
}
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session

    //var_dump($_GET['code']);
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    //$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 

        // Once the access token is retrieved, you no longer need the
        // authorization code in the URL. Redirect the user to a clean URL.
        //header('Location: '.filter_var($redirectUri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        //die();

}
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}
if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}
$blog      = $service->blogs->getByUrl('http://tapetoposty.blogspot.com/');
$blogName  = $blog->getName();
$blogUrl   = $blog->getURL();
$postsObj  = $blog->getPosts();
$postCount = $postsObj->getTotalItems();
$posts     = $postsObj->getItems();
$blogID  = $blog->getID();

$newpost = new \Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
$newpost->setTitle("2 Example post from zend");
$newpost->setContent("This is test content 3");
$newpost->setLabels(array('3d', 'blog z tapetami', 'do', 'hd', 'komputer', 'krajobrazy', 'lato', 'pulpit', 'tapeta', 'tapetoblog', 'tapety', 'tło', 'windows', 'wodospad', 'zdjęcia', 'zwierzęta', 'świąteczne'));
//$newpost->setUrl('example-url');
$newpost->setPublished('true'); //make Google_Service_Exception in /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79 Message: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1534947238029354603/posts?key=INSERT+DEV+HERE: (400) Invalid value for: Invalid format: "true"


//$newpost->setImages($images);
//$newpost->setTitleLink('title-link-example'); //make Google_Service_Exception
//  $newpost->setCustomMetaData($customMetaData); //untested
$post = $service->posts->insert($blogID, $newpost, array());


print_r($post);
```

Any help I would appreciate it.

Edit1:
Using this code

```
$now = new \DateTime('NOW');
$day = $now->modify('+17 day');
//var_dump($day);
$newpost->setPublished($day->date);
```

Lead to error ok, post was published immediately. Maybe I need to usesetCustomMetaData($customMetaData) to work properly? But I have no idea how to build $customMetaData (as i read at google docs OAuth playground this set author as well as publication date)

Edit2: Thanks @abraham for correction my mistakes, it happens as I do not use a translator.

Comment: Mmm, `$newpost->setPublished(new DateTime('NOW'));` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, given the solution is not working. Question still active.

Comment: And whats error pops out if `new DateTime('NOW')` used ? or just `'NOW'`?

Comment: No error, just execute as normal. See Edit1 in question.

Comment: You want the blogger to show post's publication date in future? But, what meaning of it? Or, You want that post to appear in blog only after some delay, like 17 days? Or you want to do something with created `$newpost` before it is actually published? Need some explanation.

Comment: Maybe, if you want create post with `draft` status, you should call `$newpost->setStatus($status);` before `$newpost->setPublished(new DateTime('NOW'));` it?

Comment: I want that message is Appear in a blog after some delay, like in example (17 days) and after this Dealy publish it. Can I do this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87099/discussion-between-brutalapple-and-ankhzet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in `javadoc` for `Google_Service_Blogger_Posts_Resource::publish()` method:

> @opt_param string publishDate Optional date and time to schedule the
>   publishing of the Blog. If no publishDate parameter is given, the post is
>   either published at the a previously saved schedule date (if present), or the
>   current time. If a future date is given, the post will be scheduled to be
>   published.

So, `Google_Service_Blogger_Post::setPublished($pubDate)` method expects string date parameter with with `RFC 3339` formatting, and proper way of publishing with desired date will be like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('+17 day'); 
$newpost->setPublished($date->format(DateTime::RFC3339));
```